# $X_n\rightarrow X$ in $L_1$ implies uniform integrability of $\{X_n\}$

Tags: probability-theory

A proposition from my probability course says that $$X_n\xrightarrow{L_1}X\quad\Rightarrow\quad X_n\xrightarrow{p} X\;\text{and u.i.}$$

It wasn't proved in class so I've tried to do it myself. I think I've got the convergence in probability part sorted, but I cannot think of how to show uniform integrability of the $\{X_n\}$. This is what I have so far:

It is sufficient to take $X=0$. Convergence in probability follows directly from Markov's inequality, $P(X_n\ge a)\le E(X_n)/a\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. For uniformly integrable property need to show $\sup_n E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>r})\to 0$ as $r\to\infty$. If not, there is some $n$ such that $E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>r})>0$ for arbitrarily large $r$. There therefore must be a set $A$ with $P(A)>0$ such that $E(|X_n|1_{A})=x>0$.

---

At this point I am not sure how to bring it all together but feel that I am close. I sort of see what's happening, we have some function $X_n$ which is "infinite" on some set $A$ with positive measure. I do not think this would contradict the limiting properties (both $L_1$ and $p$) that I have, but maybe it contradicts the $P(\Omega)=1$ assumption. Maybe I can make a stronger statement than *There therefore must be a set $A$ with $P(A)>0$ such that $E(|X_n|1_{A})=x>0$*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_n \xrightarrow[]{L^1} 0$

$$\limsup_n E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>r})\leq \limsup_n E(|X_n|) = 0 $$
Plus the fact that for fixed n
$\lim_{r \to \infty} E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>r}) = 0$

Gives the result:

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N_0: \quad E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>r}) < \epsilon $$

take $r > R_0$ such that for $n \leq N_0$$E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>r}) < \epsilon$

So for all $\epsilon >0$ there is an $R_0>0$ such that for $r > R_0$

$$\sup_n E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>r})\leq \epsilon $$

This gives that
$$\lim_{r \to \infty} \sup_n E(|X_n|1_{|X_n|>r}) = 0 $$